# How to derive the Time Dilation formula given:

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time, velocity

Since I do not have 10 reputation I will fit this all in one image:

[image]

If you have any questions please dont hesitate to ask.

**EDIT:** http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8604/myquestion2.png

Comment: it would be best if you write out what your question is, what you have tried and specify where specifically you are having problems with the question.

Comment: Hi BDillan. Welcome to Physics.SE. This site deals with conceptual Physics Q&A. Please be advised that we don't encourage homework questions that doesn't involve any sort of work done by the *author* and asks other users to solve the problem. If you think you could clarify your question, add *what you've done* along with your question. We're ready to help you. If you aren't clear, Please have a look at our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/11062) for more info. I really hate to say that [you should've a nice look at Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation)

Comment: Every resource I go to doesn't provide full derivation ~ even wiki. The derivation I did already didn't work out and is useless to post here. I just don't know where to go to ask for help....I thought if I post here the users here could have showed me the full derivation

Comment: are you able to show us what you have been able to derive so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have this:

$$D = \sqrt{(v \Delta t')^2 + L^2}$$

You seemed to recognize that you could eliminate $D$ by using equation 2, but the key you don't seem to have recognized yet is that you can eliminate $L$ by using equation 1 to get

$$c \Delta t' = \sqrt{ (v \Delta t')^2 + (c \Delta t)^2}$$

Think you can finish from here?

*Edit*: if not, then what you should do here is square both sides.

$$c^2 (\Delta t')^2 = v^2 (\Delta t')^2 + c^2 (\Delta t)^2$$

You should be able to solve for $(\Delta t')^2$ at this point.